# Javascript scope problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm having some trouble with scoping in javascript. I'm using a jquery plugin to write a class that is a wrapper for our dropdown controls.

the problem is in the `loadJsonList` function, the call to `this.addOption(s.itemValue, s.itemText);` does not work as the method doesn't exist. I know JS has odd scoping but I've no idea how i can run that function in that scope??

```
jQuery.Class.extend("DDL",
{
    id: '',
    isTelerik: false
},
{
    init: function (newid) {
        this.Class.id = newid;

    },
    getValue: function () {
        return $('#' + this.Class.id).val();
    },
    getText: function () {
        return $('#' + this.Class.id + ' :selected').text();
    },
    setValue: function (newValue) {
        try {
            $('#' + this.Class.id).val(newValue);
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    },
    setText: function (newText) {
        try {
            $('#' + this.Class.id + ' :selected').text(newText);
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    },
    loadJsonList: function (list, param1, param2, param3) {
        this.clearItems();

        //init the service
        var j = new JsonRPC();

        // get the cut down data table
        var dt = j.getDropDownData(list, param1, param2, param3);

        // parse the datatable and load it into the telerik combo box
        jQuery.each(dt, function (i, s) {
            this.addOption(s.itemValue, s.itemText);
        });
    },
    addOption: function (value, text) {
        $('#' + this.Class.id).append('<option value="' + value + '">' + text + '</option>');
    },
    removeOption: function (value) {
        $('#' + this.Class.id + ' option[value="' + value + '"]').remove();
    },
    clearItems: function () {
        $('#' + this.Class.id + ' option').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: To be slightly pedantic, when talking about `this` you're not talking about scoping but binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple one.  JavaScript uses function level scoping, so you save a reference to the `this` variable under some other name:

```
loadJsonList: function (list, param1, param2, param3) {
        // save a reference for use in the each function later
        var self = this; 
        this.clearItems();

        //init the service
        var j = new JsonRPC();

        // get the cut down data table
        var dt = j.getDropDownData(list, param1, param2, param3);

        // parse the datatable and load it into the telerik combo box
        jQuery.each(dt, function (i, s) {
            // use self instead of this!
            self.addOption(s.itemValue, s.itemText);
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` in that function's scope is not equal to the same `this` of your object, you need to assign an alias variable to it in the surrounding scope in order to access it inside the inner function:

```
var self = this;     
jQuery.each(dt, function (i, s) {
     self.addOption(s.itemValue, s.itemText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is jQuery's proxy method ([http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)):

```
// Description: Takes a function and returns a new one that will always have a particular context.
jQuery.proxy( function, context )
```

So in your above example you'd use it as follows:

```
loadJsonList: function (list, param1, param2, param3) {

   // ...

   jQuery.each(dt, jQuery.proxy(function (i, s) {
       this.addOption(s.itemValue, s.itemText);
   }, this));
},
```